# Running web server without root access

Tags: webserver, cluster

Excuse the probably simple question, I don't know much about running web servers.

I' am trying to run some [software](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/luigi) on a compute cluster I have access to on my school campus (so I don't have root access). This software has the option of running a simple webpage for me to check its status. Is there a way to run this server through one of the ports or to tunnel it through ssh?

Comment: You're right in that the software does run on the cluster with default port. My question is then how do I go about viewing the webpage at that port? For example I login to the cluster via ssh username@clustername, but going to http://clustername:8082 on my browser gives me nothing.